# Is it possible to reconstruct heat transfer coefficients from a known solution curve?

Tags: thermodynamics, calculus

This isn't a homework problem since I've never taken a class on this. Please excuse any horrible math mistakes.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to determine rough (as in, right order of magnitude) values for the convective and conductive heat transfer coefficients of some irregularly shaped stuff being heated under a lamp. I mostly just care about what effects changing air and surface temperatures will have on how quickly it heats up. I can determine the lamp's power and radiation intensity (close enough for my needs, anyway) but in order to extrapolate about the system I need a rough idea of what the other two factors are.

Edited for clarification: $ U $ is the total heat transfer coefficient due to conduction to the surface. $ h $ is the total heat transfer coefficient due to convection to the surrounding air. $ T(t) $ is the temperature of the heated object. The problem is dealing with the average case, so assumes a single object with some average parameters. $ A $ is the surface area, because I am operating under the assumption that all heat transfer laws are linked to the object's surface area. In principle one could dispose of it and leave just the coefficients.

Right now I am trying to use the following equation as basis for my calculations:
$$\frac {dQ}{dt} = -UA\Delta T_{surface} - hA\Delta T_{air} +EkA  $$
where $E$ is radiated power over area and $k$ is a fudge coefficient that depends on the shape. I assume that the surface and air don't heat up quickly enough for it to matter. U and h already include whatever fudging is required to go from the full surface area to the relevant one, because the objects are pretty uniformly shaped.

When I factor in mass m and heat capacity C I get:
$$\frac {mCdT}{dt} = -UA(T(t) -  T_{surface}) - hA(T(t)-T_{air}) +EkA $$

Then I separate out all the variables, solve (hopefully?) the differential equation and get something that looks like this:
$$ t(T)=\frac{mC}{A(U+h)}ln\Bigl|\frac{-U(T_0-T_{surface})-h(T_0-T_{air})+Ek}{-U(T-T_{surface})-h(T-T_{air})+Ek}\Bigr|  $$
where $T_0$ is the initial temperature. Expressing temperature I get something like this:
$$T(t)=\frac{(1-e^{-t\frac{A(U+h)}{mC}})(UT_{surface}+hT_{air}+Ek)}{U+h}-T_0e^{-t\frac{A(U+h)}{mC}} $$
Now, there's a pretty good chance my result is wrong since I am very, very bad at math, but I am pretty sure U+h is going to end up on both sides of the exponent no matter what I do because it is multiplied both by the changing temperature and the constant ones.

How would I even go about finding the U and h values with known values of t and T1? I can't figure out any way to express them in terms of each other, or the results.

I'm fine with using numerical methods if such exist. Am I posing the problem correctly? Are there better ways to approach it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not overly invested in this model and will replace it with something better if required.

Comment: *Am I posing the problem correctly?* It's poorly defined, IMO. What is $T(t)$ e.g.? The temperature of the object over time?

Comment: Yes. T(t) is the temperature of the object being heated. T0 is its initial temperature. I only care about the average case so I treat it as a problem with a single object being heated.

Comment: *[...] values for the convective and conductive heat transfer [...]* Yet you don't take conduction into account (which requires Fourier's heat equation).

Comment: And what heat transfer Law is $EkA$ based on?

Comment: EkA is literally just radiation power over the cross section area of the object. k is a fudge for both efficiency and the relation between the surface area and the cross section. Since the temperatures are in the room temperature range, I am not taking losses due to radiation into account or trying to figure out what the temperature of the heating element is.

Comment: I only care about losses due to conduction, not any actual conduction process in detail. So I use U instead of k/l A. I just care about what the final coefficient is, not the temperature distribution.